# How can I order a List<string>?

Tags: c#, string, list

I have this `List<string>`:

```
IList<string> ListaServizi = new List<string>();
```

How can I order it alphabetically and ascending?

Comment: Have you tried `.Sort` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx ?

Comment: Sort method; in combination with Reverse if u also need descending

Answer (score 318, accepted):

```cs
ListaServizi = ListaServizi.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

Comment: @Servy one reason to use OrderBy would be that ListaServizi doesn't have a Sort method because it's declared as `IList<string>`.  This code would actually work as written, unlike the answers that received more upvotes with `ListaServizi.Sort()`.  I'm not saying this is the solution I'd choose, but this was actually the only correct answer when I posted my answer.

Comment: If it's not the solution that you'd choose then why propose it as an answer?  Propose what you'd do as the answer; if that means changing the type from IList to List so you can call `.Sort` on it, then why not do that.

Comment: @Servy He solved the issue without changing the problem specification. That's the preferred way, by far. Moreover, the problem statement uses the interface over implementation pattern, which is very important. Proposing the change to List type is correct, but should be done as an alternative answer, after the correct one, because it requires to change the problem.

Comment: @AurélienRibon Nothing about the problem statement says that the type of the variable cannot be changed.  The requirements are very specifically to sort a `List`.  And the cost associated with this answer is non-trivial and also needless.  It literally gains *nothing*.  It adds complexity to the code, it is less concise, it's less efficient, there is literally nothing but disadvantages here.

Answer (score 60):

You can use [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
List<string> ListaServizi = new List<string>() { };
ListaServizi.Sort();
```

Answer (score 17):

Other answers are correct to suggest `Sort`, but they seem to have missed the fact that the storage location is typed as `IList<string`.  `Sort` is not part of the interface.

If you know that `ListaServizi` will always contain a `List<string>`, you can either change its declared type, or use a cast.  If you're not sure, you can test the type:

```
if (typeof(List<string>).IsAssignableFrom(ListaServizi.GetType()))
    ((List<string>)ListaServizi).Sort();
else
{
    //... some other solution; there are a few to choose from.
}
```

Perhaps more idiomatic:

```
List<string> typeCheck = ListaServizi as List<string>;
if (typeCheck != null)
    typeCheck.Sort();
else
{
    //... some other solution; there are a few to choose from.
}
```

If you know that `ListaServizi` will sometimes hold a different implementation of `IList<string>`, leave a comment, and I'll add a suggestion or two for sorting it.

Answer (score 8):

```
ListaServizi.Sort();
```

Will do that for you.  It's straightforward enough with a list of strings.  You need to be a little cleverer if sorting objects.

Comment: `ListaServizi` is `IList<string>`; the interface doesn't have a `Sort` method.  You at least need a cast here.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>()
{
    "Bob", "Bob","Alex", "Abdi", "Abdi", "Bob", "Alex", "Bob","Abdi"
};

myCollection.Sort();
foreach (var name in myCollection.Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(name + " " + myCollection.Count(x=> x == name));
}
```

output:
Abdi 3
Alex 2
Bob 4