# How to sort descending a string list contains strings with alphabets & numbers in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, alphanumeric

I have values in a string list like

```
AB1001_A
AB1001_B
AB1002_2
AB1002_C
AB1003_0
AB1003_
AB1003_B
AB1003_A
AB1001_0
AB1001_1
AB1001_2
AB1001_C
AB1002_B
AB1002_A
```

And I wanted to sort this by ascending order and the suffixes in descending order like below

```
AB1001_2
AB1001_1
AB1001_0
AB1001_C
AB1001_B
AB1001_A
AB1002_0
AB1002_B
AB1002_A
AB1003_0
AB1003_B
AB1003_A
AB1003_
```

How can I code it in C#.net?

Comment: So, what have you researched, what is not working?

Comment: I tried PadNumbers using regex. But I coudn't sort the suffix only in descending format and the remaining in ascending format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I order a List<string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211470/how-can-i-order-a-liststring)

Comment: The suffixes in your expected results are not sorted in descending order, because if they were they would be "C", "B", "A", "2", "1", "0" (numbers come before letters in alphabetical order).

Comment: See [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) and [ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby). But you will need your own comparer to sort the suffixes in the order you want

Comment: How long can the suffixes be? Are they limited to a single character? If not, can they mix letters and digits?

Comment: Also, can you explain why you have `AB1002_2` in the input but not in the expected output?

Comment: suffix always will be single character with "_". But it can be either Alphabet or number. But number should come first then alphabet in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the soln by this

```
var mystrings = new []
            {
                "AB1001_A",
                "AB1001_B",
                "AB1002_2",
                "AB1002_C",
                "AB1003_0",
                "AB1003_",
                "AB1003_B",
                "AB1003_A",
                "AB1001_0",
                "AB1001_1",
                "AB1001_2",
                "AB1001_C",
                "AB1002_B",
                "AB1002_A",
            };


mystrings.Cast<string>().OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x));
```

and then PadNumbers function as  like below

```
        public static string PadNumbers(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite strange sorting, but if you really need it, try something like this:

```
List<string> lItemsOfYourValues = new List<string>() {"AB1001_A","AB1001_B","AB1001_0" /*and next your values*/};

List<Tuple<string,string,string>> lItemsOfYourProcessedValues = new List<Tuple<string,string,string>>();
string[] arrSplitedValue;

for(int i = 0; i < lItemsOfYourValues.Count; i++) 
{

arrSplitedValue = lItemsOfYourValues[i].Split("_");

lItemsOfYourProcessedValues.add(new Tuple<string,string,string>(lItemsOfYourValues[i], arrSplitedValue[0], arrSplitedValue[1]));

}

List<string> lSortedValues = lItemsOfYourProcessedValues.OrderBy(o => o.Item2).ThenByDescending(o => o.Item3).Select(o => o.Item1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in your expected results, since `AB1002_2` is in the input but not in the expected results.

Assuming that's just an error, and further assuming that the suffixes are limited to a single character or digit, you can solve the sorting by writing a special comparer like so:

```
static int compare(string x, string y)
{
    var xParts = x.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var yParts = y.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (xParts.Length != yParts.Length)
        return yParts.Length - xParts.Length; // No suffix goes after suffix.

    if (xParts.Length == 0) // Should never happen.
        return 0;

    int comp = string.Compare(xParts[0], yParts[0], StringComparison.Ordinal);

    if (comp != 0 || xParts.Length == 1)
        return comp;

    if (char.IsDigit(xParts[1][0]) && !char.IsDigit(yParts[1][0]))
        return -1; // Digits go before non-digit.

    if (!char.IsDigit(xParts[1][0]) && char.IsDigit(yParts[1][0]))
        return 1; // Digits go before non-digit.

    return string.Compare(yParts[1], xParts[1], StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

Which you can then use to sort a string list, array or `IEnumerable<string>`, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var strings = new []
            {
                "AB1001_A",
                "AB1001_B",
                "AB1002_2",
                "AB1002_C",
                "AB1003_0",
                "AB1003_",
                "AB1003_B",
                "AB1003_A",
                "AB1001_0",
                "AB1001_1",
                "AB1001_2",
                "AB1001_C",
                "AB1002_B",
                "AB1002_A",
            };

            static int compare(string x, string y)
            {
                var xParts = x.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var yParts = y.Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (xParts.Length != yParts.Length)
                    return yParts.Length - xParts.Length;

                if (xParts.Length == 0)
                    return 0;

                int comp = string.Compare(xParts[0], yParts[0], StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (comp != 0 || xParts.Length == 1)
                    return comp;

                if (char.IsDigit(xParts[1][0]) && !char.IsDigit(yParts[1][0]))
                    return -1; // Digits go before non-digit.

                if (!char.IsDigit(xParts[1][0]) && char.IsDigit(yParts[1][0]))
                    return 1; // Digits go before non-digit.

                return string.Compare(yParts[1], xParts[1], StringComparison.Ordinal);
            }

            var stringList = strings.ToList();
            stringList.Sort(compare);

            Console.WriteLine("Sorted list:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", stringList));

            var stringArray = strings.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(stringArray, compare);

            Console.WriteLine("\nSorted array:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", stringArray));

            var sequence = strings.Select(element => element);
            var sortedSeq = sequence.OrderBy(element => element, Comparer<string>.Create(compare));

            Console.WriteLine("\nSorted sequence:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", sortedSeq));
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRIfcl)